# C# Linq - order IEnumerable by count of identical property

Tags: c#, linq, count, sql-order-by

I am trying to find a Linq expression, where I can order my IEnumerable consisting of

string Country
string City
bool IsCapital

in a way that the new IEnumerable lists all objects, but the order is

1. County, but the country with most cities in the list first, then the country with second most entries, and so on
2. ThenBy City

my first try is

```
IEnumerable allCities = new Enumerable { 
//initialize list
};

allCities = allCities
.OrderBy(x => x.Country)
.ThenBy(x.City);
```

but of course the number of cities within the same country are not taken into account.

I appriciate your help, thank you in advance.

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Linq `GroupBy()` method as:

```
// 1. Group by country
// 2. Order descending by the count of each group
// 3. Select all objects of all groups (ordered) to a flat list
var result = cities
    .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.OrderBy(x => x.City))
    .ToList();
```

This list of objects:

```
var cities = new List<MyObj>
{
    new MyObj { Country = "Germany", City = "Frankfurt" },
    new MyObj { Country = "Norway", City = "Oslo" },
    new MyObj { Country = "Italy", City = "Rome" },
    new MyObj { Country = "Germany", City = "Berlin" },
    new MyObj { Country = "Germany", City = "Munich" },
    new MyObj { Country = "France", City = "Paris" },
    new MyObj { Country = "Italy", City = "Milano" },
};
```

...would give the result:

Germany - Berlin
Germany - Frankfurt
Germany - Munich
Italy - Milano
Italy - Rome
Norway - Oslo
France - Paris

Answer (score 0):

For this you need the concept of `Counties with their zero or more Cities`. Once you've got that, you can order the Counties by the number of Cities, and Order the Cities per County.

Result: Ordered Counties (by descending number of Cities), and every City ordered by Name

If you want to flatten this into combinations of [County, City, IsCapital] you can use `SelectMany` to do this.

First you have to group all items by same County. Alas you forgot to give your [County, City, IsCapital] a class name, so I'll give it the name `GeographicalItem`

```
IEnumerable<GeographicalItem> inputData = ...
```

Make Groups of `Counties with their Cities`:

```
var result = inputData.GroupBy(geographicalItem => geographicalItem.County,

// parameter resultSelector: for every Country, with all geograhpicalItems in this
// country make one "Country with its cities"
(country, geographicalItemsInThisCountry) => new
{
    Country = country,
    Cities = geoghraphicalItemsInThisCountry.Select(geographicalItem => new
    {
        Name = geographicalItem.City,
        IsCapital = geograhpicalItem.IsCapital,
    })
    .OrderBy(city => city.Name)
    .ToList(),
})
```

Result: sequence of Countries, each Country with a list of Cities in that Country, ordered by Name. Each City has a Name and a property IsCapital.

Now order the Countries: Countries with most Cities first:

Continuing the LINQ:

```
.OrderByDescending(country => country.Cities.Count)
```

Result: Sorted Countries, each Country with its Sorted Cities. The Country with the most Cities first. The cities within a Country ordered by Name.

If you want to flatten the result: use SelectMany:

```
.SelectMany(county => country.Cities,

// parameter resultSelector: from every [country, city] combination make one new:
(country, city) => new
{
    Country = country,
    City = city.Name,
    IsCapital = city.IsCapital,
});
```